# Log rotation on IoT Edge Agent

Tags: azure, docker, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am following Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist#solution-management) and trying to set the logs for **edge Agent** through the container options. My deployment.template.json file is as follows:

```
{
 "$schema-template": "2.0.0",
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {
            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
            "loggingOptions": "",
            "registryCredentials": {
              "myRegistryName": {
                "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME",
                "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD",
                "address": "myRegistryAddress.azurecr.io"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "LogConfig": {
                      "Type": "json-file",
                      "Config": {
                          "max-size": "10m",
                          "max-file": "3"
                      }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "5671/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "5671"
                      }
                    ],
                    "8883/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "8883"
                      }
                    ],
                    "443/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "443"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "LogConfig": {
                    "Type": "json-file",
                    "Config": {
                        "max-size": "10m",
                        "max-file": "3"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "Module_Name": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.Module_Name}",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "LogConfig": {
                      "Type": "json-file",
                      "Config": {
                          "max-size": "10m",
                          "max-file": "3"
                      }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "routes": {
          "route": "FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream"
        },
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I build and deploy it on my device, edge Hub and my module log rotation are applied but edgeAgent log rotation is not applied. I check the log rotation settings in the 
/var/lib/docker/containers/{container_id}/hostconfig.json file.

**What I have done so far:**

Removed the image through `sudo docker rmi sudo docker rmi mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0` and removed all the containers including the edgeAgent container and restarted the edge environment by `sudo systemctl restart iotedge`. The log rotation is still not applied to the new container created by the edge run time. I am not sure, what am I missing ? Any help is appreciated. **Please note**, I don't want to apply log rotation by creating a daemon.json file and placing it in the edge run time folder. I need to do it through the container options specified in the deployment.template.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug where edge agent deployment does not apply if version number is identical to the one in config.yaml; please help to create a github issue for it.  To workaround, please set the options in config.yaml.

Comment: You can use the workaround described here from the deployment: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1590#issuecomment-527545210 to